# Spring security | Why do I get bad credentials when they are valid?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, jwt

So I am working on a Spring boot project and security is one of the things I want to have in this project.
I am having this problem where my code always goes to the BadCredentialsException, but I thought my credentials are correct.

**My AuthenticationController:**

```
@RestController
@CrossOrigin
public class JwtAuthenticationController {

    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    @Autowired
    private JwtTokenUtil jwtTokenUtil;


    @Autowired
    private JwtUserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/authenticate", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ResponseEntity<?> createAuthenticationToken(@RequestBody JwtRequest authenticationRequest) throws Exception {

        authenticate(authenticationRequest.getUsername(), authenticationRequest.getPassword());


        final UserDetails userDetails = userDetailsService
                .loadUserByUsername(authenticationRequest.getUsername());

        final String token = jwtTokenUtil.generateToken(userDetails);


        return ResponseEntity.ok(new JwtResponse(token));
    }

    private void authenticate(String username, String password) throws Exception {
        try {
            authenticationManager.authenticate(new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(username, password));
        } catch (DisabledException e) {
            throw new Exception("USER_DISABLED", e);
        } catch (BadCredentialsException e) {
            throw new Exception("INVALID_CREDENTIALS", e);
        }
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/register", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ResponseEntity<?> saveUser(@RequestBody UserDTO user) throws Exception {
        return ResponseEntity.ok(userDetailsService.save(user));
    }
}
```

**My UserDetailsService:**

```
@Service
public class JwtUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {
    @Autowired
    private UserDao userDao;
    @Autowired
    private PasswordEncoder bcryptEncoder;

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        DAOUser user = userDao.findByUsername(username);
        if (user == null){
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("User not found with username: " + username);
        }
        return new User(user.getUsername(), user.getPassword(), new ArrayList<>());

    }
    public DAOUser save(UserDTO user) {
        DAOUser newUser = new DAOUser();
        newUser.setUsername(user.getUsername());
        newUser.setPassword(bcryptEncoder.bCryptPasswordEncoder().encode(user.getPassword()));
        return userDao.save(newUser);
    }
}
```

**My WebSecurityConfig:**

```
@Configuration
@AllArgsConstructor
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {//provides security for endpoints

    @Autowired
    private JwtAuthenticationEntryPoint jwtAuthenticationEntryPoint;

    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService jwtUserDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    private JwtRequestFilter jwtRequestFilter;

    private final AccountService accountService;
    private final BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder;

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        // configure AuthenticationManager so that it knows from where to load
        // user for matching credentials
        // Use BCryptPasswordEncoder
        auth.userDetailsService(jwtUserDetailsService).passwordEncoder(bCryptPasswordEncoder);
    }

    @Bean
    @Override
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .csrf().disable()//So we can send post requests without being rejected(if we using form based indication we want to enable this)
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/authenticate","/register")
                .permitAll()//any request that goes trough that end point we want to allow.
                .anyRequest()
                .authenticated().and().exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(jwtAuthenticationEntryPoint)
                .and().sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                .and().addFilterBefore(jwtRequestFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);

    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.authenticationProvider(daoAuthenticationProvider());
    }

    @Bean
    public DaoAuthenticationProvider daoAuthenticationProvider() {
        DaoAuthenticationProvider provider =
                new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        provider.setPasswordEncoder(bCryptPasswordEncoder);
        provider.setUserDetailsService(accountService);
        return provider;
    }
}
```

**My RequestFilter:**

```
@Component
public class JwtRequestFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    @Autowired
    private JwtUserDetailsService jwtUserDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    private JwtTokenUtil jwtTokenUtil;
    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain chain)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        final String authorizationHeader = request.getHeader("Authorization");

        String username = null;
        String jwt = null;

        if (authorizationHeader != null && authorizationHeader.startsWith("")){
            jwt = authorizationHeader.substring(7);
            username = jwtTokenUtil.extractUsername(jwt);
        }

        if (username != null && SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication() == null){
            UserDetails userDetails = this.jwtUserDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(username);
            if (jwtTokenUtil.validateToken(jwt, userDetails)){
                UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                        userDetails, null, userDetails.getAuthorities());
                usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken
                        .setDetails(new WebAuthenticationDetailsSource().buildDetails(request));
                SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken);
            }
        }
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }


}
```

**My PasswordEncoder:**

```
@Configuration
public class PasswordEncoder{

    @Bean
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder(){
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }




}
```

**My UserDao**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "myusers")
public class DAOUser {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;
    @Column
    private String username;
    @Column
    @JsonIgnore
    private String password;

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

}
```

**My UserDao Interface**

I know the name is confusing, but I just followed the tutorial and he gave it this name, I have not changed it, because I want it to work before I rename files.

```
@Repository
public interface UserDao extends CrudRepository<DAOUser, Integer> {
    DAOUser findByUsername(String username);
}
```

I think these are all the files you need to help me. if you need more, just ask and I will upload them.
Can anyone help me with this problem?
Thanks!!

Comment: One problem I see here is in the WebSecurityConfig. DaoAuthenticationProvider is provided as a @Bean and hence Spring will initialize it for you. But in configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) you create another new instance by calling daoAuthenticationProvider() which is not a Spring Managed bean but a separate instance.

Answer (score 0):

if you read the [spring documentation on passwords](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html5/#authentication-password-storage-dpe-format) (which you should of done before you ask here)

you will see that the format when storing a password is:

```
{bcrypt}$2a$10$dXJ3SW6G7P50lGmMkkmwe.20cQQubK3.HZWzG3YB1tlRy.fqvM/BG
```

While when you are storing it you are just storing it and not adding the `{bcrypt}` prefix to the generated string before you store it.

```
newUser.setPassword(bcryptEncoder.bCryptPasswordEncoder().encode(user.getPassword()));
```

So when you are later providing a password, you are getting bad password since spring does not know what encoder to use when decoding the password.